# Using a Windows 10 PC to control which image is shown full-screen on an Android device

Tags: windows, android, presentation

I wish to present images to an audience who will be looking at an Android tablet, but I will personally **not** be touching that tablet to switch between images. Instead, I want to use my Windows PC to select which image is currently shown on the tablet. In other words, I wish to run some sort of presentation and use my Windows PC to control which slide is currently visible on the tablet, the issue being that I cannot predict in which order I will need to show the slides, and I wouldn't want to show the images in-between slides that I am navigating to/from.

Assume that the PC and the tablet will be on the same WiFi network. Security is not a concern. Also, it is not an issue if the images need to be uploaded on the tablet beforehand, or if there is a lengthy preparation process. The solution does not need to be free.

Bonus points if I can also use the solution to show videos as well (not just images) and/or play music on the Android tablet from the PC -- but certainly not mandatory.

Note that I am not looking for "screen mirror" applications as I will be doing other things on the Windows PC in the meantime, which are not meant to be broadcasted to the Android tablet.

I am curious to hear your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

If you create your presentations to use [Reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/#/) for presenting (there are several ways to do this but outside of the scope of your question) then you can use the [Reveal.js multiplex](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#multiplexing) option.

This will involve:

- Creating your slides as static HTML pages (with just about any acceptable content - including video) & can include speaker notes with the plug-in
- Starting your show from reveal as master
- Having a Socket.io server running on the local network *(if this is on the same machine you can't have speaker notes)* or using a service such as GitHub Pages, Amazon S3, Dreamhost, Akamai, etc. for a publically accessible location.
- Your audience connects to the server page from their web browser.
- They get to see what you show them.

All of the above software is available free, open source & cross platform there are likely to be fees for using some of the publicly available services.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have upvoted it. Since this was going to require a lot of technical work either way, I decided to just program my own little Websocket-based tool and I used it for my presentation. Your guidance was very good and I appreciate it!